# Como faço uma Alert message UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Boas,

Como faço um alert? do jeito que fiz parece estar tudo correcto excepto pelo erro da função.

alguma ajuda, desde ja agradeço.

[image: Print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Swift 3, o método *presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)* foi substituído por *present(_:animated:completion:)*

```
self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Boas, Rafael essa ja foi, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O erro original era que você havia chamado "presentedViewController", que é uma propriedade, em vez de "presentViewController()" que é um método. Foram duas letrinhas, é fácil confundir :-)